# How to change text color in DjView 4.12 on mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, ventura

Using the default `DjVuLibre DjView 4.12` (DjVuLibre-3.5.28, Qt-4.8.7) on Ventura 13.5 the content of a djvu file is shown in blue letters.

Is it possible to change the color?

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around-solution: Replacing `djview @4.12_1` with `djview-qt5` in MacPorts solved the foreground color to black.

Maybe there is a better solution around.